# Write / add data in JSON file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

I am trying to write JSON file using node from loop data, e.g.:

```js
let jsonFile = require('jsonfile');

for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    jsonFile.writeFile('loop.json', "id :" + i + " square :" + i * i);
}
```

outPut in loop.json is:

```
id :1 square : 1
```

but I want output file like this (below) and also if I run that code again it should add that new output as elements in same existing JSON file:

```json
{
   "table":[
      {
         "Id ":1,
         "square ":1
      },
      {
         "Id ":2,
         "square ":3
      },
      {
         "Id ":3,
         "square ":9
      },
      {
         "Id ":4,
         "square ":16
      },
      {
         "Id ":5,
         "square ":25
      },
      {
         "Id ":6,
         "square ":36
      },
      {
         "Id ":7,
         "square ":49
      },
      {
         "Id ":8,
         "square ":64
      },
      {
         "Id ":9,
         "square ":81
      },
      {
         "Id ":10,
         "square ":100
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to use same file that I created 1st time but whenever I run that code new elements should add in that same file

```js
const fs = require('fs');

let obj = {
    table: []
};

fs.exists('myjsonfile.json', function(exists) {

    if (exists) {

        console.log("yes file exists");

        fs.readFile('myjsonfile.json', function readFileCallback(err, data) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);

                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    obj.table.push({
                        id: i,
                        square: i * i
                    });
                }

                let json = JSON.stringify(obj);
                fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json);
            }
        });
    } else {

        console.log("file not exists");

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            obj.table.push({
                id: i,
                square: i * i
            });
        }

        let json = JSON.stringify(obj);
        fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 587, accepted):

If this JSON file won't become too big over time, you should try:

1. Create a JavaScript object with the table array in it

   ```
   var obj = {
      table: []
   };
   ```
2. Add some data to it, for example:

   ```
   obj.table.push({id: 1, square:2});
   ```
3. Convert it from an object to a string with `JSON.stringify`

   ```
   var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
   ```
4. Use fs to write the file to disk

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', callback);
   ```
5. If you want to append it, read the JSON file and convert it back to an object

   ```
   fs.readFile('myjsonfile.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){
       if (err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
       obj = JSON.parse(data); //now it an object
       obj.table.push({id: 2, square:3}); //add some data
       json = JSON.stringify(obj); //convert it back to json
       fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', callback); // write it back 
   }});
   ```

This will work for data that is up to 100 MB effectively. Over this limit, you should use a database engine.

UPDATE:

Create a function which returns the current date (year+month+day) as a string. Create the file named this string + .json. the fs module has a function which can check for file existence named fs.stat(path, callback).
With this, you can check if the file exists. If it exists, use the read function if it's not, use the create function. Use the date string as the path cuz the file will be named as the today date + .json. the callback will contain a stats object which will be null if the file does not exist.

Comment: Or you can also use the [jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) Node package which wraps all the complexities not shown in the code above.

Comment: if you want to pretty print it: ** `const fsp = require('fs').promises;
            const json = JSON.stringify(matterData, null, 4);
            await fsp.writeFile('all-matter.data', json, "utf8");'** don't forget that you need to put it in an [async](https://mzl.la/3hRtL4o) function if you want to use **await**..

Comment: @Jeach is the `jsonfile` package still used because you have to handle with `callback` as parameter and `require`?

Comment: I think the `callback` param does not exist with the [new fs promises](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options) package.

Answer (score 53):

Please try the following program. You might be expecting this output.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = {}
data.table = []
for (i=0; i <26 ; i++){
   var obj = {
       id: i,
       square: i * i
   }
   data.table.push(obj)
}
fs.writeFile ("input.json", JSON.stringify(data), function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('complete');
    }
);
```

Save this program in a javascript file, say, square.js.

Then run the program from command prompt using the command `node square.js`

What it does is, simply overwriting the existing file with new set of data, every time you execute the command.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 35):

For synchronous approach

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(jsonVariable));
```

Answer (score 27):

try

```
var fs = require("fs");
var sampleObject = { your data };

fs.writeFile("./object.json", JSON.stringify(sampleObject, null, 4), (err) => {
    if (err) {  console.error(err);  return; };
    console.log("File has been created");
});
```

Answer (score 16):

you should read the file, every time you want to add a new property to the json, and then add the the new properties

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('data.json',function(err,content){
  if(err) throw err;
  var parseJson = JSON.parse(content);
  for (i=0; i <11 ; i++){
   parseJson.table.push({id:i, square:i*i})
  }
  fs.writeFile('data.json',JSON.stringify(parseJson),function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
  })
})
```

Comment: thanks for reply
i tried its working but how to check if old file is exists then run readlfile code
else run writeFile direct to create new file 
i am creating daily new file with current date in file name
and i want new data to be add in that old file whole day when this code run

Answer (score 16):

Above example is also correct, but i provide simple example:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var sampleObject = {
    name: 'pankaj',
    member: 'stack',
    type: {
        x: 11,
        y: 22
    }
};

fs.writeFile("./object.json", JSON.stringify(sampleObject, null, 4), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    };
    console.log("File has been created");
});
```

Answer (score 9):

For formatting jsonfile gives `spaces` option which you can pass as a parameter:

```
   jsonfile.writeFile(file, obj, {spaces: 2}, function (err) {
         console.error(err);
   })
```

Or use `jsonfile.spaces = 4`. Read details [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile).

I would not suggest writing to file each time in the loop, instead construct the JSON object in the loop and write to file outside the loop.

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var obj={
     'table':[]
    };

for (i=0; i <11 ; i++){
       obj.table.push({"id":i,"square":i*i});
}
jsonfile.writeFile('loop.json', obj, {spaces:2}, function(err){
      console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Promise based solution [Javascript **(ES6)** + Node.js **(V10 or above)**]

Write to the File:

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises; 
fsPromises.writeFile('myFile.json', JSON.stringify({ name: "Sridhar", salary: 1234 }))
        .then( () => { console.log('JSON saved'); })
        .catch(er => { console.log(er);});
```

Append to the File:

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;
fsPromises.readFile('myFile.json', 'utf8') 
        .then(data => { 
                let json = JSON.parse(data);
                json.myArr.push({name: "Krishnan", salary: 5678});

                fsPromises.writeFile('myFile.json', JSON.stringify(json))
                        .then(  () => { console.log('Append Success'); })
                        .catch(err => { console.log("Append Failed: " + err);});
            })
        .catch(err => { console.log("Read Error: " +err);});
```

If your project supports Javascript **ES8** then you could use **asyn/await** instead of native promise.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with above answers, Here is a complete read and write sample for anyone who needs it.

```
     router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

        console.log(req.body);
        var id = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);

        var tital = req.body.title;
        var description = req.body.description;
        var mynotes = {"Id": id, "Title":tital, "Description": description};
        
        fs.readFile('db.json','utf8', function(err,data){
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            obj.push(mynotes);
            var strNotes = JSON.stringify(obj);
            fs.writeFile('db.json',strNotes, function(err){
                if(err) return console.log(err);
                console.log('Note added');
            });

        })
        
        
    });
```