# NodeJS not writing to file. Middleware not working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am currently trying to make my middeware write json data to a file after is logged in. My issue is that whenever I execute the **function**, nothing gets written to the file nor output in the console.

I've used this question as an example [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856232/write-add-data-in-json-file-using-node-js)
but still nothing works.

Here is the middleware part of my **NodeJS** script:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    dbx.accounts.findOne(function(err, info){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(info.username));
        return info;

        var xx = info.username;
        var date = new Date();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(date));
        var obj = {
           users: []
        };

        fs.readFile('logs.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){

        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
        obj.users.push({time: date, name: xx});
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
            obj = JSON.parse(   ); //now it an object
            obj.users.push({time: date, name: xx}); //add some data
            json = JSON.stringify(obj); //convert it back to json
            fs.writeFileSync('logs.json', json, 'utf8', JSON.stringify(output)); // write it back 
        }});

    });


    //logs.stamps.push({id:----, timestamp:date.toString()})

    console.log('here is Authenticated', req.isAuthenticated()) //prints out 'here is Authenticated' if the Passport login is successful
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }else{
        console.log("routes Print log You Cannot Log in!");
    }
}
```

I am trying to write **username** and **date** to the file by querying it with Mongo first: `dbx.accounts.findOne(function(err, info)`

> Why is my middleware not writing to the json file as supposed?

EDIT:

I've put the `return` statement like this:

fs.readFile('logs.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
obj.users.push({time: date, name: xx});
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
    obj = JSON.parse(   ); //now it an object
    obj.users.push({time: date, name: xx}); //add some data
    json = JSON.stringify(obj); //convert it back to json
    return info; 
    fs.writeFileSync('logs.json', json, 'utf8', JSON.stringify(output)); // write it back 
}});
```

but it still doesn't write to the file.

Comment: you are returning from you function `return info` before reaching the code which writes in your file.

Comment: yeah, the function terminates on *`return`*

Comment: Where should I place it? I just put it after the `if` statement and it still doesn't write.

Comment: update your code what did you try latest

Comment: @ricky I've updated my question.

Comment: You're still returning before the execution reaches the write command.

Comment: `return info`
should be last line

Comment: @Teemu can you paste me a fiddle please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return

Comment: @Teemu yeah I just move my `return` statement after ` fs.writeFileSync` and it still doesn't run. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: what error are you getting? and where are calling `isLoggedIn` fucntion ?

Comment: Please only add the tags relevant to the question, not your complete stack as a precaution. People are browsing questions by topic in order to answer questions specific to tags.

Comment: Are you even passing anything to JSON.parse() ?

Comment: @MilanVelebit I wasn't sure why it's not working. Am I supposed to pass any objects?

Comment: Yes, whichever JSON you want to parse, if you want to parse `obj` as, well, `obj`, then do obj=JSON.parse(obj) (however stupid that may look). I believe you should clarify your code a little bit, it's quite confusing.

Comment: @MilanVelebit you helped me quite a lot with this since it helped me to spot that I don't need to parse anything. Look at my answer if you want to see what I've changed.

P.S. Thanks everybody for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks for all the help regarding this questions. I figured out what was wrong with quite a lot of help from you guys.

I completely removed the `return info` statement since I didn't really need it.
Secondly I removed the `obj = JSON.parse(obj)` because it's already being parsed by the  **javascript interpreter**. I also removed the **JSON.stringify(output)** because I'm not using the output anywhere.

Thanks for the help and sorry if I caused any confusion.