# How to add a non-existing data in JSON file using js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a json file `data.json` it has 3 fields `id, name and address`. I want to add a new object in that file using JS at runtime through some function. How can I do that?

Comment: @libik I tried the same. It didn`t worked out sir. :)

Comment: I hope you're talking about node since you haven't tagged it in your question

Comment: @SajalPreetSingh yes, do you have any reference to the solution?

Comment: Refer https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-make-a-JSON-file-with-JavaScript

Comment: Thanks @SumeshTG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write/add data in JSON file using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856232/write-add-data-in-json-file-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file has

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Binayak",
    address: "stackoverflow"
}
```

You can use fs to read & write file

```
const fs = require('fs');

let data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8");
data = JSON.parse(data);
data.myKey = {
    new: "object"
}

fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(data));
```

will give

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Binayak",
    address: "stackoverflow",
    myKey: {
        new: "object"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to open the file in node, read the parse the json content, modify the js variable and then stringify and save the results.

This might be what you're looking for:
const fs = require("fs");

```
//Reads the file, and executes function on completion
fs.readFile("DIRECTORY_TO_FILE/data.json", "utf-8", (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  let data = JSON.parse(result);

  //Modify your data object here

  //Saves the file, make sure to provide the right directory
  fs.writeFile(
    "DIRECTORY_TO_FILE/data.json",
    JSON.stringify(data),
    "utf-8",
    function(err) {
      console.log("File saved successfuly!");
    }
  );
});
```