# Node Js saving File but no content

Tags: node.js

I have a little problem with node js.

If I save a file with fs.writeFile it saves but the file has no content, but if I read the file and print the content there is content in the file

Thats the node js code to save the file:

```
let sjson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./saves/User_VipList.json", "utf8"));
    sjson['users'].push({"name": args[0]});
    fs.writeFile("./saves/User_VipList.json", JSON.stringify(sjson), (err) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      
    });
```

Thats how i read the content:

```
let sjson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./saves/User_VipList.json", "utf8"));
    console.log(sjson);
```

And that's the JSON file:

```
{
    "users": []
}
```

But in users should be content because

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: Did you set correct permission before you write the file?

Comment: Do i need permissions for node js in Windows and if its needed how do i set it :)?

Comment: I thought your are using linux. Did you try to push a sample data like sjson['users'].push({"name": "john"}); if still not solve the problem remove "" in your name property just {name: "john"}, maybe its a json error

Comment: I tested if it write the a txt file but same problem

Comment: I think you need to use readFileCallback, experiment with this [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856232/write-add-data-in-json-file-using-node-js ]

Answer (score 0):

Due to async nature looks like your program doesnt wait when file write ends occurs, so please try to use [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) instead, for example:

```
try {
  fs.writeFileSync("./saves/User_VipList.json", JSON.stringify(sjson))
} catch(err) {
  console.log('Error writing file:', err)
}
```

Comment: Seems like this didn't fix it file is still empty. but there is still output with content.

Comment: try to check what content in `sjson`, and after stringify by inserting `console.log(sjson)` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(sjson))` before fs.writeFileSync

Answer (score -1):

**Found the Problem**

Oh i think i found the problem if i start node index.js with a bat file the problem happends but if i start node manually over cmd it works.

Didn't mention the Bat file because i didn't think thats could be a problem :)

But why is that a problem?