# How to store an array in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm using discord.js and am trying to get a block command to store its value in an array. In other words, when I do /block  It will ignore that person, but I want it to store it in a file so it stays after restarting. My current code is below:

```
//at the top
var { blockedUsers } = require('./blocked.json')

//in the command listener
if (command == 'block') {
    let user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user && !blockedUsers.includes(user.id)) blockedUsers.push(user.id);
    message.channel.send(`blocked!`)
}
```

blocked.json:

```
{
"blockedUsers": []
}
```

This works fine, but after restarting the bot, the blocked list clears. How can I get it to store it in the file so that it stays after restarting?

Comment: Using require, you get access to the JSON data, no the file.

Try using `fs` library to write your JSON file.

Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856232/write-add-data-in-json-file-using-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using require on a JSON file, you are evaluating the file content as a JavaScript object, which lives independently of the JSON source file.

For persisting the modifications in the file, use this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile("./blocked.json", JSON.stringify({ blockedUsers }), function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```