# How to download json file to cloud storage on app engine node.js standard environment

Tags: node.js, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a web application on GAE node.js standard environment. The server receives a POST request containing json in its body (not ready json file). I want to write this json file to Cloud Storage. How to do this?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write JSON file to `/tmp` directory using `fs.createWriteStream` and then write it to Storage using Storage API

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the body (the JSON) and save it in a [cloud storage file](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/file#_google_cloud_storage_File_save_member_1_). That should be enough

Answer (score 0):

To consume the body of your post request, you can check a previous discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005939/how-do-i-consume-the-json-post-data-in-an-express-application). On the other hand, if you specifically want to convert it to a JSON file, check this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856232/write-add-data-in-json-file-using-node-js). Continuing with the upload, you can consult the [documentation example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs) where this is the suggested procedure (please visit the page for the full script for the recommended variable paths and the links to the Cloud Storage Node.js API reference):

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function uploadFile() {
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filePath, {
    destination: destFileName,
  });

  console.log(`${filePath} uploaded to ${bucketName}`);
}

uploadFile().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `req.rawBody` not `req.body`.  Here is a full working example:

```
exports.getData = (req, res) => {

// The ID of your GCS bucket
const bucketName = 'yourBucket';
// The new ID for your GCS file
const destFileName = 'yourFileName';
// The content to be uploaded in the GCS file
const contents = req.rawBody;
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
// Import Node.js stream
const stream = require('stream');
// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();
// Get a reference to the bucket
const myBucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
// Create a reference to a file object
const file = myBucket.file(destFileName);

// Create a pass through stream from a string
const passthroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();
passthroughStream.write(contents);
passthroughStream.end();

async function streamFileUpload() {
  passthroughStream.pipe(file.createWriteStream()).on('finish', () => {
    res.status(200).send('OK');
  });

  console.log(`${destFileName} uploaded to ${bucketName}`);
}

streamFileUpload().catch(console.error);

};
```