# Cannot use 'callback' with fs, Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fs

Yo, I have this peice of code in my API and it gives me an error I don't understand.

Code :

```
server.get('/deleteall', async (request, reply) => {
  var json = JSON.stringify(deleteall);
  fs.writeFile('todos.json', json, 'utf8', callback);
  return 'File overwritten.'
})
```

Error :

```
Argument of type '(arg0: string, json: string, arg2: string, callback: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NoParamCallback'.
```

The error happens on build, I don't understand it at all, keep in mind, this is my first TS experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `callback` argument for [`fs.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback) is [defined](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/fs.d.ts) like this:

```
export type NoParamCallback = (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null) => void;
```

Whatever you have defined as `callback` does not match that type definition. It should be something like:

```
function callback(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Or specified inline:

```
fs.writeFile('todos.json', json, 'utf8', (err) => console.log(err));
```

---

As a more general comment: I suggest you migrate to the [promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api) to escape callback hell.

Comment: I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36856787) guide, here's my [full code](https://pastebin.com/6rsuPAVc)

Comment: Right. As I said: that `callback` method you define at the end does not match the expected signature.