# How do I update schema changes in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

Currently, my Mongo db schema has a model called **namecards**. And inside the namescards, there are documents called profile(object), links(array of objects), and so on...

```
namecards: {
    profile:{
        address:{...},
        phoneNumber:{...},
        ...
    },
 
    links:[{...}]
}
```

By the way, I want to push only a few documents of the namecards profile and links in the array of objects called **blocks**.

**Update Expected Schema**

```
namecards:{
    blocks:[
        {
        address:{...},
        links:[],
        and new added columns , ...        
    },
    {...}
    ]
}
```

***The question here is,***

1. Should I delete the profile and link documents of the namecards as soon as I don't need them?
2. If you don't delete it, how is the best way to define a schema?

i tried just add and added... but it didn't wise solution....

Answer (score 0):

Actually changing a schema is bit difficult and if you want to change it in production we use the following steps :

1. We Iterate over the documents of the table .
2. For each element we just change the data at it's format
3. Then we update it inside json file . [Refer to this to learn about
   how to store data in a json file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856232/write-add-data-in-json-file-using-node-js)

This is how you have stored important data inside backup.json file
After this we can safely change the schema
and run a simple query forEach element in json file to insert the data .

> This are the best practices we do in production level so that our data
> is not lost for newer updates or for newer features