# How to put a user who used a command in a .json/.txt file [DISCORD.JS]

Tags: file, error-handling, discord.js, writefile

When someone use a command of my bot, like: `/ban Player123 ReasonXYZ`. I want the User who got banned with the reason and the user who banned **Player123** is in a file named `"banlist.json"`

Sorry for bad english

```
const banlogmsg = message.author.tag + '  |  ' + (banreason) + ' |  ' (bannedplayer)

fs.writeFileSync('./banlog.json', JSON.stringify(banlogmsg))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write / add data in JSON file using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36856787/15446076)

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to actually send the file in a message. It's also better to use Buffer (integrated into nodejs) instead of fs.

```
let channel = message.channel;
let banlogmsg = message.author.tag + '  |  ' + (banreason) + ' |  ' (bannedplayer);

channel.send({files:[{attachment:Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(banlogmsg)),name:`banlog.json`}]});
```

I hope that answers your question.