# Can I use a localhost, created using node.js, to store all data submitted on my website? with no SQL or any DB. Just HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

The question is very much the same as it is on title, my absolute doubt about it, is if this is possible? all I've read about server side application lead to a DB like SQL or something aside from web.

So I would like to know if is it possible to simple submit something on a textarea and store on a server application made by node.js

for example:

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();


//here is where I got with some help of others questions on stackoverflow
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Note that in version 4 of express, express.bodyParser() was
//deprecated in favor of a separate 'body-parser' module.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
})
```

```html
<div class="Contact_info">
        <h1 id="Resume">Nos aconselhe</h1><!-- Give us some advice form -->
        <form id="formCritic"         action="http://localhost:3000"  method="get"> <!-- this is my localhost created using JS on node.js -->
            <input type="text" id="Name" name="Nome" placeholder="Seu nome.." >
            <textarea class="text_area_submit" id="Questio" name="Questio" placeholder="Nos informe qualquer duvida ou problema.." ></textarea>
<!-- here is the text area which I would like to store what users input on my localhost -->

            <input id="submit_text_are" type="submit" value="Submit">
          
        </form>
</div>
```

Just some extra info, I have my root directory, named : Myproject

inside it there are 5 folders + Index.html

one folder name is JS, which rely my js program to my html and my serverSide.js made by node.js.

I'm adding this information, because I've already seen a lot of answers on some questions here that might treat this matter about where your folder which you've created your serverSide with node.js important.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Do you think there's a fundamental difference between your PC and a server? Just run a database on your PC.

Comment: it is not about that, i know that i can use my local pc, im just intend here display something on a plain html and use it as a "data base" to store user's opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store data in json file, for example. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36856787/17146534) or [here](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/).
But it's not a great idea for a real application.

For your case something like this should work.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON and urlencoded data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/saveInput', (req, res) => {
    // Get the message from the request body
    const { Nome, Questio } = req.body;
    console.log( Nome, Questio )
    // Write the message to a JSON file
    const data = JSON.stringify({  Nome, Questio }) + '\n';
    fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'message.json'), data, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error writing message to file:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        } else {
            console.log('Message written to file');
            res.status(200).send('Message written to file');
        }
    });
});

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:${port}/`);
});
```

```html
<script>
document.getElementById('formCritic').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior

    const formData = new FormData(this);
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/saveInput', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
});


</script>

<div class="Contact_info">
    <h1 id="Resume">Nos aconselhe</h1><!-- Give us some advice form -->
    <form id="formCritic" action="http://localhost:3000/saveInput" method="post"> <!-- Specify the POST method and endpoint -->
        <input type="text" id="Name" name="Nome" placeholder="Seu nome.." >
        <textarea class="text_area_submit" id="Questio" name="Questio" placeholder="Nos informe qualquer duvida ou problema.." ></textarea>
        <input id="submit_text_are" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Just make sure you have a file message.json in the directory.

Comment: Worked the exaclty way i was lonking for, thank you a lot my friend, now i would think over in way when i submit the page just got updated, but stay still on my 'Home page' instead of change the page to one where the has a paragraph on it 'Message written to file'

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to simple submit something on a textarea and store on a server aplication made by node.js

Yes.  But you're probably misunderstanding a few things.

You *can* store data "in the application" in the form of just saving it to a variable in a more global scope, for example.  But that data will be very short-lived.  It's not persisted anywhere, so as soon as anything happens to the running application that data will be gone.

> with no SQL or any DB. Just HTML

You *can* also write your data to HTML files.  Though as a data storage format HTML is very loosely structured and this is going to very quickly become difficult to manage.

You could store your data in any format you like though.  So perhaps serializing to a JSON file would make more sense.  It's persisted outside of the application, so it'll survive a reboot.  It's in a structured format.  That could work for you.

Though as that data scales to any significant amount, or as the need to read and write the data reaches any higher volumes than just you alone, writing it to the file system becomes less performant and more cumbersome.

The solution to that is to use a database.

Comment: Its just very simple form where i will get user's opinion about my website on a text area, as you says, i guess im gonna use JSON for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage in the browser

However you don't 'submit' to localSorage because submit means a http request.  However you can use javascript code for the submit and in that code you can store the values in localStorage, and, if necessary, attempt to submit them to a server.

This approach is used by some sites to remember what you typed in fields, even if you leave and even if you close the browser, they can subsequently be retrieved when displaying a form again.